# Streaming Analytics job not receiving inputs from IOT hub

Tags: input, azure-iot-hub, stream-analytics

I followed a [IOT Hub tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted) and got it working.  I then created a Stream Analytics job and used the above as an Input (which upon test connection works).

However I do not see any inputs being received.  When running a sample test I get the following error:

> Description Error code: ServiceUnavailable Error message: Unable to
>   connect to input source at the moment. Please check if the input
>   source is available and if it has not hit connection limits.

I can see telemetry messages being received in the IOT Hub.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem with an Event Hub input. I know that it was working before. I've been following the troubleshooting steps and tested the connection which is working fine. Continuing to troubleshoot...

Comment: I have the same problem with an IoT Hub input. I have tested with sample data it's working fine. but it's not receiving the events from IoT hub while job running.

Answer (score 3):

Is the stream analytics job running?

I had a similar problem where i wasn't getting any events from stream analytics and i had forgotten to turn it on.

Click on the stream analytics > overview > start

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (using Event Hubs in my case). The root cause was that I had too many queries within my job running against the same input. I solved it by splitting my input into several inputs across multiple consumer groups.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs) (emphasis added):

> Each Stream Analytics IoT Hub input should be configured to have its own consumer group. When a job contains a self-join or multiple inputs, some input may be read by more than one reader downstream, which impacts the number of readers in a single consumer group. **To avoid exceeding IoT Hub limit of 5 readers per consumer group per partition**, it is a best practice to designate a consumer group for each Stream Analytics job.

Comment: My job is very simple, I'm sending a temperature reading from a Rasberry PI temp sensor.  I only have one device & one stream analytics job.  As mentioned I can see the IOT hub is receiving the telemetry (i.e. {temp: 23.45} ) . I have created a specific consumer group for the SA job & ensured the resource group is consistent across both the IOT Hub & Stream Analytics job.  But no luck!

Comment: How many queries are in your SA job? Does the job and the sampling work when you reduce it to just a single query (including any `WITH... AS` subqueries)?

Comment: I should add that I've also had quite a bit of trouble with stability issues for the past few days. Deleting outputs -- and even deleting jobs -- doesn't seem to work. I'm planning to contact Support for help but have been working around the issues to meet a deadline. So I wouldn't be too surprised if my suggestion isn't helpful and something else is causing your problem. :)

Comment: Only x1 query, with a very straight forward query:  SELECT
    *
INTO
    [RasPiOutput]
FROM
    [InputRasPi]  error: Description
Error code: ServiceUnavailable Error message: Unable to connect to input source at the moment. Please check if the input source is available and if it has not hit connection limits. 
Status
Error

Comment: Hmmm. What does the job's diagnostic log show? (New feature as of yesterday :))

Comment: i just idded a new consumer groupe , but it's still not pulling message fro mthe iot hub, did any one found the solution for this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, though my modules on my raspberry pi are running without failure.

SA says: "Make sure the input has recently received data and the correct format of those events has been selected.